# How to fix this simple Python program? I think I have got the logic wrong

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have tried to create a game in python. There are two players, they roll a die and their total score is updated. The first to reach 100 wins. The output of this program is very weird. I get 35 NumPy arrays like this one: [0]. According to my inexperienced brain, I have got everything right.

```
# Snakes and Ladders (2 players)
import numpy as np

player_one_score = np.array([0])
player_two_score = np.array([0])

for p1 in range(30) :

        player_one_roll = np.random.randint(1,7)
        np.append(player_one_score, player_one_roll)
        if player_one_score == 100 :
        print('Player 1 won!') 
        else :
        print(player_one_score)

        player_two_roll = np.random.randint(1,7)
        np.append(player_two_score, player_two_roll)
        if player_two_score == 100 :
        print('Player 2 won!')
        else :
        print(player_two_score)
```

Comment: What do you expect and what is the output?

Comment: I don't really understand why it is necessary to use `numpy`... Also, wouldn't you want to be using a while loop rather than a for loop since the winner is whoever wins 100 times first?

Comment: And one shouldn't check if the score is `== 100` but if it's `>= 100` .

Comment: The [tag:pygame] tag is intended to be used for questions related to the [PyGame](https://www.pygame.org/news) library.

Comment: Please write a title which describes your problem. Read this page on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html), `np.append` does not modify the original array, unlike Python's `list.append`. It instead returns a new array containing the original array along with the new appended values. Instead of just writing

```
np.append(player_one_score, player_one_roll)
```

You should instead write

```
player_one_score = np.append(player_one_score, player_one_roll)
```

Reading further into the code, it looks like you have a couple of indentation errors. The if/else statements should look something like this:

```
 if player_one_score == 100 :
    print('Player 1 won!') 
 else :
    print(player_one_score)
```

Additionally, if the win condition is for the total to be over 100, the `sum` of `player_one_score` array should be used like so:

```
 if sum(player_one_score) >= 100:
    print('Player 1 won!') 
 else:
    print(player_one_score)
```

The same goes for `player_two_score` (Also note the change from `==` to `>=`).

Lastly, like Pouya said, you don't really need NumPy for something like this. Using vanilla Python is probably the best way to learn coding. You should also look into `while` loops; they should be used instead of `for` loops for something like this.

Example:

```
while ( sum(player_one_score) < 100 or sum(player_two_score) < 100 ):
   # Code here
   # ...
```

though you would want to store the conditions in a variable so the code doesn't look as ugly.